# How can i set the slack variables in cplex to 0?

Tags: variables, slack, cplex

When I go to see how cplex calculated the constraints, in some the slack variables are different from 0. For example if I have a constraint where, replacing the decision variables, it returns me 6 <= 15 as the slack variable it gives me 8. Or in equality constraints 1 == 0 gives me 1. I want to set them all to 0, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the relation off for variables:

[image]

Comment: I only activated the last one, but I continue to dare slack values, even negative ones. What could I have done wrong?